# How to properly apply constraint group validations?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I want to write a class validation. But the following does not result in an error. Why?

```
   class TestVO {
        @AssertTrue
        public boolean testDefault() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    errors = validator.validate(new TestVO());
    assertTrue(!errors.isEmpty()); //this fails. there are no errors! Why?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, as this is probably usefull as knowledge base: hibernate validations do ONLY work on `get()` methods. So modifying above to `getTestDefault()` works.